# phpexcel cell value

Tags: phpexcel

I'm looking for a way of turning integers in to coordinates to use in a cell merge luckily the items are all on the same row.

I've had a look but can't see if a function exists for this already?

So I would have

$startColumn = 0;
$endColumn = 2;

Any ideas on how I would be able to convert these to be able to use them in the following:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('a1:c1');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$startColumn = 0;
$endColumn = 2;

$mergeRange = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($startColumn) . '1:' .
              PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($endColumn) . '1';
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($mergeRange);
```